# How to deactivate User Persp (Local) view?

Tags: 3d-view

I am accidentally going to User Persp (Local) view, and I don't know how to get back to a normal Perspective view..

When I'm in the User Persp (Local), I can see the objects on the viewport, but when I render it.. I got nothing in the render result

[image: User Persp (Local)]

The point is, how to get back to normal perspective view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To go back to Global perspective view, go to View -> "View Global/Local". The hotkey is <kbd>Numpad /</kbd>. You probably pressed this when you accidentally switched to local view. This also works for otho view as well, from global to local and back. (Just to add it in, here's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWoc-ZNYfVk) explaining how it can be used to un-clutter your scene for easier editing.)

[image]

**Edit**: For Blender 3.0 to 4.0 (so far) it looks like this:

View Menu > Local View > Toggle Local View

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Problem is solved. I had to press "\".

Comment: this is **not** the right answer. The only `\` shortcut in blender is for the node editor, and is added by the node wrangler  addon.